# Book or paper recommendations in the field of Marketing and Advertising Statistics

Tags: machine-learning, references, marketing

I come from a stats background, but am currently working in a marketing/advertising statistics setting. I would like to see how stats is applied to this field so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. I would love to see, for example, how mixed models are used to asses promotion effectiveness, if such material exists. Any resources to help me get grounded would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book is quite well-reviewed, and has a bunch of interesting marketing case studies.

> Rossi, Peter E., Greg M. Allenby, and Rob McCulloch. Bayesian
>   statistics and marketing. John Wiley & Sons, 2012.

Two interesting papers I liked on online advertising and marketing which are a bit more statistical were:

> Brodersen KH, Gallusser F, Koehler J, Remy N, Scott SL. Inferring
>   causal impact using Bayesian structural time-series models. Annals of
>   Applied Statistics, 2015, Vol. 9, No. 1, 247-274.
>   http://research.google.com/pubs/pub41854.html

and

> Blake, Thomas, Chris Nosko, and Steven Tadelis. "Consumer
>   heterogeneity and paid search effectiveness: A large‐scale field
>   experiment." Econometrica 83.1 (2015): 155-174.

There's also some quite interesting research that comes out of [Google](https://research.google.com/pubs/EconomicsandElectronicCommerce.html) and [Facey](https://research.fb.com/category/economics-and-computation/) on these topics, although again it's more focused on online stuff. See for instance:

> Wang, Yueqing, et al. "A Hierarchical Bayesian Approach to Improve
>   Media Mix Models Using Category Data." (2017).

or

> He, Xinran, et al. "Practical lessons from predicting clicks on ads at
>   facebook." Proceedings of the Eighth International Workshop on Data
>   Mining for Online Advertising. ACM, 2014.

Comment: This is a nice book. I think that it falls more on the statistics side than on the marketing side with the exception of the case studies. The case studies are very useful.

Comment: I've updated my response with some further papers/resources of interest.

Comment: Wang, Yueqing, et al. "A Hierarchical Bayesian Approach to Improve
Media Mix Models Using Category Data." (2017). Is what I was looking for. Are media mixed models similar to marketing mixed models?